# Adding a second row of x-axis values in a different format in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm wondering how I could **add another row of x-axis values** right below (along side) the current x-axis values (i.e., 0 to 1) that begin from (ie., 0% to 100%)?

**To summarize in 3 steps:**
**(A):** the second row of axis values need NOT have tick marks. **(B):**, the second row of axis values  need to appear exactly below each corresponding value of the first x-axis values. **(C):**, the second row of axis values must show a "**%**" **sign** next to them.

[image]

```
 plot(1, ty='l', ann = F, axes = F, xlim = c(0, 1) )

axis(1, at = round(seq(0, 1, len = 9), 2), font = 2, cex.axis = 1.2 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up `pos`, `tck`, and `tick` of `axis`

```
par(mar = c(10,3,3,3))
plot(1, 1, type = 'l', ann = F, xlim = c(0, 1), xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = round(seq(0, 1, len = 9), 2), font = 2, cex.axis = 1.2 ) #First axis    
axis(1, at = round(seq(0, 1, len = 9), 2),
    labels = paste(100* round(seq(0, 1, len = 9), 2),"%",sep=""),
    pos = par("usr")[3] - 1 * 0.1 * (par("usr")[4] - par("usr")[3]),
    tick = FALSE, font = 2, cex.axis = 1.2) #2nd axis labels
```

Comment: Dear d.b., I'm guessing you misunderstood my question. **First**, the second row of axis values need NOT have tick marks. **Second**, the second row of axis values  need to appear exactly below each corresponding value of the first x-axis values. **Third**, the second row of axis values show have a "**%**" sign next to them.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: d.b., Yes, Perfecto!

Comment: d.b, how can I lift the second row of x-axis values a bit up?